# How can I see the list of all the triggers defined on a Db?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

For MS Sql, how can I see the list of all the triggers defined on a Db?

(The reason I need this is one of the columns in one db table seems to be modified by some trigger(s) )

Thanks!

Comment: @Parkyprg: Well, reading the question is a prerequisite for answering it...

Comment: Sorry, just noticed.... Speed reading.... See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSSql:

```
select B.Name as TableName,A.name as TriggerName
from sysobjects A,sysobjects B
where A.xtype='TR'
AND A.parent_obj = B.id
```

Answer (score 0):

from http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/archive/2004/02/27/999.aspx

SELECT trigger_name = name, trigger_owner = USER_NAME(uid), table_name = OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj),
  isupdate = OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger'), isdelete = OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger'),
  isinsert = OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsInsertTrigger'), isafter = OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsAfterTrigger'),
  isinsteadof = OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsInsteadOfTrigger'),
  status = CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled') WHEN 1 THEN 'Disabled' ELSE 'Enabled' END
FROM sysobjects
WHERE type = 'TR'